# How do I execute this command using crontab?

Tags: unix, cron

I run a list of tests using this command: "./kaboom testlist" which is written in Python.

This command can only be excuted in the directory /e/m/user/testing3/kaboom

I want to run this command every night at midnight using a cronjob. The only examples I've found online are prewritten shell scripts. So, I am not sure how to format this into a crontab so that it does what I want.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Make a shell script that changes the current directory and runs the python script

Answer (score 4):

Say you want to run a job every night at 10pm then the crontab would look like:

```
00 10 * * * (cd  /e/m/user/testing3/kaboom ; ./kaboom testlis ) > /tmp/cronjob.log 2>&1
```

Crontab entry just contains the commands you want to execute.

For examples on timings please check this [geekStuff link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/).